`Ctrl+]` on Wayland
I'm using Arch Linux with Wayland (Sway) with a German keyboard. Layout is probably setup in the Sway config, and all keys in my Alacritty terminal work as expected.
My problem is that I cannot seem to get the combination Ctrl+] to work as is used in vim-help. On my German keyboard, I need to press AltGr+9 to get the character ], which works. However, Ctrl+AltGr+9 only gives Ctrl+9, but not Ctrl+]. How do I fix this?
Around a month ago, when I had Manjaro XFCE (running X11), the combination Ctrl+AltGr+9 worked as expected.
